# Boxplot for only values that satisfy a condition in R

Tags: r, boxplot

I have [this dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8clGpnMSCjUbjgyZjd0RVFYbGM/view?usp=sharing). I want to make side-by-side boxplots of only those movies whose indexes appear 67 times in the "movie" column. The following code tells me the indexes that appear 67 times in the "movie" column:

```
names(which(table(votes$movie) == 67))
```

But how can I make side-by-side boxplots for the **"rating" each of these indexes**? And how can I **also add the averages** as a single point on each of those boxplots?

I have tried:

```
boxplot(votes$rating[which(table(votes$movie) == 67)])
```

But this is clearly wrong, as it shows me only one boxplot

MRE:

```
# set.seed(1)
# votes2 <- votes[sample(1:nrow(votes), 100, TRUE), ]

votes2 <- 
  structure(list(user = c(869L, 620L, 42L, 341L, 930L, 267L, 708L,934L, 148L, 385L, 251L, 181L, 313L, 437L, 747L, 260L, 109L, 201L,229L, 366L, 921L, 829L, 934L, 868L, 321L, 226L, 527L, 726L, 26L,457L, 117L, 325L, 327L, 60L, 804L, 158L, 593L, 200L, 880L, 482L,868L, 339L, 328L, 347L, 100L, 896L, 846L, 676L, 357L, 496L, 541L,807L, 257L, 924L, 894L, 478L, 601L, 13L, 311L, 230L, 435L, 654L,742L, 180L, 887L, 201L, 147L, 326L, 749L, 465L, 727L, 200L, 216L,267L, 345L, 445L, 268L, 26L, 366L, 82L, 763L, 436L, 324L, 707L,802L, 280L, 682L, 343L, 826L, 325L, 508L, 618L, 405L, 655L, 645L,378L, 296L, 438L, 450L, 151L), movie = c(181L, 240L, 410L, 948L,143L, 926L, 1054L, 502L, 474L, 47L, 147L, 125L, 527L, 249L, 659L,319L, 576L, 1426L, 245L, 672L, 1028L, 151L, 492L, 90L, 182L,250L, 7L, 248L, 841L, 222L, 307L, 434L, 318L, 132L, 746L, 510L,692L, 79L, 585L, 269L, 739L, 485L, 679L, 386L, 347L, 686L, 12L,303L, 597L, 532L, 304L, 820L, 285L, 173L, 52L, 71L, 208L, 333L,504L, 266L, 961L, 195L, 294L, 216L, 491L, 179L, 304L, 655L, 62L,855L, 222L, 756L, 226L, 217L, 303L, 902L, 825L, 255L, 671L, 1128L,283L, 568L, 259L, 212L, 646L, 144L, 566L, 88L, 174L, 99L, 172L,44L, 482L, 863L, 674L, 696L, 292L, 269L, 722L, 443L), rating = c(3L,5L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 3L,2L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L,4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 4L,5L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 2L,5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 4L,5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L,4L, 5L, 5L),
timestamp = structure(c(884490825, 889987954, 881110483,890758169, 879535462, 878970785, 877326158, 891194539, 877019882,879441982, 886272319, 878962816, 891013525, 880142027, 888639175,890618198, 880580663, 884114015, 891632385, 888858078, 879380142,891990672, 891192087, 877109874, 879439679, 883890491, 879456162,889832422, 891380200, 882392853, 880124339, 891478376, 887820828,883325944, 879444890, 880134296, 886193724, 884128499, 880175050,887643096, 877111542, 891032413, 885049460, 881654846, 891375212,887159146, 883947777, 892685403, 878952080, 876072633, 883864207,892532068, 882049950, 885458060, 882404507, 889388790, 876350017,881514810, 884364873, 880484286, 884133635, 887864350, 881005590,877128388, 881379566, 884114471, 885593942, 879875432, 878849052,883531444, 883709350, 876042493, 880244803, 878973760, 884900448,891200870, 875742893, 891377609, 888857990, 884714361, 878915600,887769416, 880575107, 886286792, 875986155, 891700514, 888519260,876405130, 885690481, 891479244, 883767157, 891308791, 885544739,887473995, 892054402, 880045044, 884196057, 879867960, 882471524,879524947), class = c("POSIXct","POSIXt"), tzone = "")),
.Names = c("user","movie", "rating", "timestamp"), row.names = c(26551L, 37213L,57286L, 90821L, 20169L, 89839L, 94468L, 66080L, 62912L, 6179L,20598L, 17656L, 68703L, 38411L, 76985L, 49770L, 71762L, 99191L,38004L, 77745L, 93471L, 21215L, 65168L, 12556L, 26723L, 38612L,1340L, 38239L, 86970L, 34035L, 48209L, 59957L, 49355L, 18622L,82738L, 66847L, 79424L, 10795L, 72372L, 41128L, 82095L, 64707L,78294L, 55304L, 52972L, 78936L, 2334L, 47724L, 73232L, 69274L,47762L, 86121L, 43810L, 24480L, 7068L, 9947L, 31628L, 51864L,66201L, 40684L, 91288L, 29361L, 45907L, 33240L, 65088L, 25802L,47855L, 76632L, 8425L, 87533L, 33908L, 83945L, 34669L, 33378L,47636L, 89220L, 86434L, 38999L, 77733L, 96062L, 43466L, 71252L,40000L, 32536L, 75709L, 20270L, 71113L, 12170L, 24549L, 14331L,23963L, 5894L, 64229L, 87627L, 77892L, 79731L, 45528L, 41009L,
81088L, 60494L), class = "data.frame")

names(which(table(votes2$movie) == 2))
# [1] "222" "269" "303" "304"

boxplot(votes2$rating[which(table(votes2$movie) == 2)])
```

[image]

Comment: says right at the top - R is a free, open-source programming language and software environment for statistical computing, bioinformatics, and graphics. **Please supplement your question with a minimal reproducible example. Use dput() for data** and specify all non-base packages with library calls....

Comment: The dataset is right there in the first line of my post included as a hyperlink "this dataset". Maybe you didn't see it at first because I forgot to include the link when I first posted my question and then it took me a minute to include the link.

Comment: 1) that file is almost 3M, you have 100,000 observations in this data, do you consider that _minimal_?; 2) your ratings are discrete with 5 values, I don't think you want a boxplot; 3) `nn <- names(which(table(votes$movie) == 67)); vv <- votes[votes$movie %in% nn, ]; boxplot(rating ~ movie, vv)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, as I understand the request as being for the side by side boxplots for ratings where the votes are exactly 67 in number:

```
boxplot( movie ~ rating,  data=votes, 
                subset = movie %in% names( table(votes$movie) == 67)), 'rating' ])
```

Switched the order in my first guess at correct formula but testing should this was more successful on your example:

```
 boxplot(movie~rating, data=votes2, subset = movie %in% names( table(votes2$movie) == 2))
```

[image]

You should probably do a search on rhelp and SO for plotting a point or text for the mean of categories on boxplots. Pretty sure this has been asked before. If unsuccessful, then report on the search terms used.